# About some standard results from functional analysis

Tags: functional-analysis, reference-request

Recently I was reading some text on Banach algebra.

The book `Banach Algebra and automatic continuity` By Dales has a long reference. In its appendix, he references the following functional analysis result, in the following:

$E$ is a Banach space and $F$ is a closed subspace of $E$, $F'' = (F')' $ and $F^{\perp \perp} = (F^\perp)^\perp$ and $F^\perp = \{f \in E': \langle f, x \rangle = 0, \forall x \in F\}$.

> Let $F$ be a closed linear subspace of a normed space $E$.
>
> (i) For each $\lambda \in F'$, take $\Lambda \in E'$ with $\| \Lambda
>  \| = \| \lambda \|$ and $\Lambda | F = \lambda$. Then the map $\lambda
>  \mapsto \Lambda + F^\perp$, $F' \to E' /F^\perp$ is an isometric
> linear bijection
>
> (ii)Let $\pi : E \to E/F$ be the quotient map. Then the map $\pi' :
>  (E/F)' \to F^\perp$ is an isometric linear bijection.
>
> (iii) $F'' = F^{\perp \perp} = \overline{F}{}^{(\sigma)}$, where
> $\sigma = \sigma(E'', E')$
>
> (iv) $(E/F)'' \cong E'' / F^{\perp \perp}$.

---

(iii) has been answered here: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4718519/549321

How can I prove (iv)

Comment: It would help if you would explain the notation.

Comment: $F^{00}$ should be the bipolar $F^{\circ\circ}$. (iii) is a consequence of Hahn-Banach (in the form of the bipolar theorem) because the dual of $(E'',\sigma(E'',E'))$ consists of evaluations in points of $E'$.

Comment: @NateEldredge Thanks, the notation is added

Comment: @Jochen Maybe my "bipolar" definition is different from yours. But $F^{00}$ here means the annihilator of the annihilator

Comment: For subspaces the polar is equal to the annihilator.

Comment: @Jochen could you explain more about this "bipolar theorem", since the  "bipolar theorem" I saw is about ${}^0(F^0) \subset E$ is the weak closure of $F$ in $E$, here my $F^{00} \subset E''$, $E$ and $E''$ are different spaces. Actually, I can prove $F^{00} =\overline{F}{}^{\sigma}$ this using Goldstine's theorem, but I don't know if I missed something