# double dual of a subspace can be embedded into the double dual

Tags: functional-analysis, reference-request

Notation:
$E$ is a Banach space and $F$ is a closed subspace of $E$, $G$ is a closed subspace of $E'$, $F'' = (F')' $ and $F^{\perp \perp} = (F^\perp)^\perp$ and $F^\perp = \{f \in E': \langle f, x \rangle = 0, \forall x \in F\}$, $ {}^\perp G= \{x \in E: \langle f, x \rangle = 0, \forall f \in G\}$.

When I am reading some papers,

The author wrote something like this:
Let $E$ be a Banach space, $F \subset E$ being closed, then $F''$ can be embedded into $E''$, as a subspace, in this case, the following three are equal:

1. $F''$ (considered as a subspace)
2. $F^{\perp \perp}$(defined as $F^{\perp \perp} = (F^\perp)^\perp$, a subspace of $E''$, this is not ${}^\perp(F^\perp)$.)
3. the w*-closure of $F$ in $E''$

I can prove 2 is equal to 3, using the bipolar theorem and Goldstine's theorem. About 1 is equal to 2, the author said using the double adjoint of the inclusion map $i: F\to E$, my question is how to prove 1 is equal to 2?

The following is my previous question, if you can provide some books mentioning this fact, it would be very good, too:
[About some standard results from functional analysis](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4715235/549321)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $E$ is a Banach space and $F$ is a closed subspace of $E$, we
also defined $F'' = (F')' $ and $F^{\perp \perp} =
(F^\perp)^\perp$, then $F''$ can be embedded into $E''$, as a subspace, in this
case, the following three are equal:

(i) $F''$ (considered as a subspace of $E''$).

(ii) $F^{\perp \perp}$(this is a subspace in $E''$, not ${}^\perp(F^\perp)$.)

(iii) the w*-closure of $F$ in $E''$

Proof for (i) $\Leftrightarrow$ (ii).

Let $\rho_X: X \to X''$ and $\rho_M: M \to M''$ be the
natural maps. If $i: M \to X$ is the inclusion map, shows
that there is an isometry $\Phi: M'' \to X''$ such that the
diagram:

[image]

commutes. We have $\phi(M'') = (M^\perp)^\perp$ [Indeed, we have
$M'' = (X'/M^\perp)' = (M^\perp)^\perp$. The explicit form of
$\phi$ is: given $m'' \in M''$ and $x' \in X'$, $\phi(m'')(x') =
m''(x'\restriction_M)$]. In fact, this can also be obtained by the
double adjoint of the inclusion map $i: M \hookrightarrow X$.

Proof for (ii) $\Leftrightarrow$ (iii) is straightforward from the Bipolar Theorem